# 404 error page intermittently returned for SXA XML sitemap

Tags: sxa, sitemap

*Sitecore 9.1
SXA 1.8*

When trying to access the XML sitemap on our website, a 404 page is returned about 25% of the time. It works 75% of the time. We have a multisite configuration, with an XML sitemap for each site.
In the 'Settings' item we have '*Sitemap Mode*' set to '*Stored in cache*'.
We shouldn't need to set the '*Target Hostname*' property on the '*Site Grouping*' site, as it only prefills the hostname for a URL if it's unknown (and you get the /sitecore/content/etc... paths).

Our logs show the following error:

> ERROR Application error. Exception: System.Web.HttpException Message:
>   File does not exist. Source: System.Web    at
>   System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String
>   virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)
>   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext
>   context, String overrideVirtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> 17348 14:58:22 WARN  Could not find proper static error page for site:
>   SITENAME. Please generate it. 17348 14:58:22 INFO  SitemapHandler
>   (sitemap.xml) : cannot resolve site or url
>   (https://www.xyz.com/error-404?404;https://APPSERVICENAME__9650:80/VIRTUALFOLDERNAMEOFOURSITE/sitemap.xml)
>   17348 14:58:22 WARN  WebUtil.QueryStringCache cache is cleared by
>   Sitecore.Caching.Generics.Cache`1+DefaultScavengeStrategy[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] strategy. Cache running size was
>   17.5 KB.

We can see where the error is coming from:

Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin
SitemapHandler process:

```
public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
{
  Uri url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
  if (!url.PathAndQuery.EndsWith("/sitemap.xml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    return;
  if (this.CurrentSite == null || !UrlUtils.IsUrlValidForFile(url, this.CurrentSite, "/sitemap.xml"))
  {
    Log.Info("SitemapHandler (sitemap.xml) : " + string.Format("cannot resolve site or url ({0})", (object) url), (object) this);
  }
  else
  {
    Item settingsItem = this.GetSettingsItem();
    SitemapStatus sitemapStatus = settingsItem != null ? settingsItem.Fields[Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.Templates.Sitemap._SitemapSettings.Fields.SitemapMode].ToEnum<SitemapStatus>() : SitemapStatus.Inactive;
    string sitemap;
    switch (sitemapStatus)
    {
      case SitemapStatus.Inactive:
        Log.Info("SitemapHandler (sitemap.xml) : " + string.Format("sitemap is off (status : {0})", (object) sitemapStatus), (object) this);
        return;
      case SitemapStatus.StoredInCache:
        sitemap = this.GetSitemapFromCache();

        ...
```

So it fails before it tries to retrieve the sitemap from the cache. By the time the *Log.Info* is hit in the above code, the URL is also a 404 URL (see logs above).

I can see the below from using a dll search (using Agent Ransack) on Sitecore.Kernel:

> ...Cannot resolve the IP address of the web server with the specified
>   hostname: {0}.
>
> rawUrl+{0}_sitecore_username{0}_{1}placeholderTypeflagNameparameterName?404;

- Could it be that the 'GetHostIPAddress' method below (where the same warning is present) has anything to do with this, given the proximity above?

In Sitecore.Kernel - Sitecore.Web - WebUtil - GetHostIPAddress, we have the following method:

```
public static string GetHostIPAddress()
    {
      HttpContextWrapper httpContext = WebUtil.GetHttpContext();
      try
      {
        return WebUtil.GetHostIPAddress((HttpContextBase) httpContext);
      }
      catch (SocketException ex)
      {
        Log.SingleWarn(string.Format("Cannot resolve the IP address of the web server with the specified hostname: {0}.", (object) httpContext.Request.Url.Host), (object) typeof (WebUtil));
      }
      return string.Empty;
    }
```

So we have two questions:

- Where does the 404 URL in the above error message get generated?
- Why is our URL rewritten to https://APPSERVICENAME__9650:80/VIRTUALFOLDERNAMEOFOURSITE/sitemap.xml from https://www.xyz.com/VIRTUALFOLDERNAMEOFOURSITE/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason why this was happening was because of SXA bug 393910:

> https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Accelerator/10x/Sitecore%20Experience%20Accelerator%201000/Release%20Notes

This is fixed in SXA version 10.0.0.